# using preg_replace OR pre_replace_callback to replace new lines within bbcode

Tags: php

I've written a bbcode parser that is basically called this way:

```
echo nl2br(bb_parse($contents));
```

I'm updating the function to be ready for PHP 5.4+ by using preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace with the e modifier.

```
function strip_newline($text) 
{ 
     return preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", "", $text); 
}

bb_parse($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace("/\[ul\](.*)\[\/ul\]/Usie", '"<ul class=\"forum_unordered\">".strip_newline("$1")."</ul>"', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

I'm having trouble using preg_replace_callback to accomplish the same thing.

```
bb_parse($text)
{
    $text = preg_replace_callback("/\[ol\](.*)\[\/ol\]/Usi", create_function('$matches', 'return preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", "", $matches);'), $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

**Edit**

The code that bbcode that I wish to parse is this:

```
[ol]
[li]One[/li]
[li]Two[/li]
[/ol]
```

My problem is that there are three line breaks between [ol] and [/ol] that I wish to remove.  Without removing the line breaks the output becomes this:

```
1. One

2. Two
```

Instead of:

```
1. One
2. Two
```

Comment: The first $matches is an array, the second $matches must be one of the values, $matches[0] or $matches[1]

Comment: If you are future-proofing then it would make sense to use a closure/anonymous function instead of the `create_function` call.

Comment: @Akam Is it possible to do multiple replacements in this way?

Comment: @knittl How would I create the anonymous function?  I'm not very familiar with them yet.

Comment: Yes you can please see more [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: @user2040588: e.g. `preg_replace_callback('/your pattern/', function($matches) { doYourStuff(); }, $subject);`

Comment: Still am not able to get the described functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I Think problem is here must put **$matches[1]**

```
bb_parse($text)
{
  $text = preg_replace_callback("/\[ol\](.*)\[\/ol\]/Usi", function($matches){       
    return preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", "", $matches[1]);
   }, $text);
   return $text;
}
```